# How do the Selenium bindings work, and how do I use them?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Note: This may be more of a "meta" issue of how to understand documentation rather than a specific issue with the Selenium bindings themselves.

I'm looking at the [Selenium Python bindings](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html), and I'm a bit confused.

Most examples of how to start a simple instance of the browser require something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("www.google.com")
```

Now, I look at the [webdriver.firefox object](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html) and I see that there are four methods associated with that object! I'm sure there should be more than this. Where, for instance, is `.get()` in my example?

So I start looking around and I see that there are a bunch of methods I can use on the `webdriver.Firefox()` object in [webdriver.remote](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=get#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get). But this doesn't seem to make sense? I'm not using `webdriver.remote`? Why are all these methods in here?

Finally, my confusion is compounded by the fact that there's [selenium.selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/selenium/selenium.selenium.html#module-selenium.selenium), which has a host of interesting and powerful methods, but I have no idea how to use them. Then don't work on the `webdriver.Firefox()` object, so how do I use them? Why do they never appear in any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webdriver.Firefox() is in fact webdriver.firefox.WebDriver.

Just have a look on the code in [selenium/webdriver/__init__.py](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py) and [selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py), which inherits a lot from the RemoteWebDriver class.

There is a short [introduction to the selenium python bindings](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings), too. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest, if I do `from selenium import webdriver` and then specify the "unaliased" path: `browser = webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver()`, it works fine, but if I do `import selenium`, then doing `browser = selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver()` isn't recognised?